# Pyspark structured streaming, how to stop or restart job if it fails?

Tags: pyspark, offset, spark-structured-streaming, checkpoint

Pyspark structured streaming, how to stop or restart job if it fails? I am new to this so want to understand
1.How checkpointing helps while restart
2.Do we need to call any method to passing offset when we restart
3.Also,I want to know how to stop job, if have any changes in code logic so as to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes! That is the point of using the checkpoint, to failure
   recovery https://www.databricks.com/blog/2015/01/15/improved-driver-fault-tolerance-and-zero-data-loss-in-spark-streaming.html
2. If you are using Yarn (also EMR that use yarn), you can set the
   property spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html but thats
   it.
3. One way is using yarn kill command https://sarathkumarsivan.medium.com/how-to-kill-all-applications-running-on-yarn-2052289a7e7, there are multiple ways to implement this, all depends in where is the Job running.

Comment: Also, if the job fail for any reason that is not a code error, such us memory, the cluster fail, etc. You can restart the job pointing to the same checkpoint path and thats it.

Comment: I am using databricks CLI to restart cluster, Can you add few points like how in production this actually happens